A compact Kähler manifold that admits a homogeneous action of a non-reductive Lie group
Is it possible to have a compact Kähler manifold that admits a homogeneous action of a non-reductive Lie group? It seems not to be the case, but a precise argument of reference would be great!
Edit: To clarify, I am asking about smooth actions.

I guess that "homogeneous" means "transitive". Also you certainly want a faithful action since otherwise there are trivial examples (e.g., any non-reductive Lie group acting on a point).

Is your action by smooth isometries, just smooth, or something else?

If the action is isometric, the isometry group being compact, every transitive subgroup will be reductive. But indeed one should clarify. Does it mean a holomorphic action, regardless of the Kähler structure?
